# How to find similarity distance between vector and matrix (matrices that are not the same size) in python?

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

I have a dataset of user's 'preferences' table, an instance of that table looks like this:

```
print(user_normalized[1].reshape(1, -1).shape)
print(user_normalized[1].reshape(1, -1))
___________________________________________________________________
(1, 20)
[[0.         0.00239107 0.00131709 0.         0.00355872 0.00212352
  0.00300639 0.00044287 0.001469   0.00358637 0.01520913 0.
  0.         0.         0.00174978 0.00237691 0.0026616  0.00241604
  0.         0.        ]]
```

Which gives me first user's preference vector.

And I have a dataset of movie's content table:

```
print(movie_content.shape)
print(movie_content)
___________________________________________________________________
(27278, 20)
[[1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

I am trying to get dot product of user's preference vector and movie's content table in order to find most preferential movies (cosine similarity):

```
distances = np.dot(user_normalized[1], movie_content)
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,20) and (27278,20) not aligned: 20 (dim 1) != 27278 (dim 0)
```

Is it the right way to find distance measure in order to find most preferential movies?

If it is what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape the vector to `(-1, 1)`. If you want to take a dot product of two arrays of shape `(m, k)` and `(t, n)` then `k` must be equal to `t`. As there is no concept of vectors in numpy, you basically have an array of shape `(27278, 20)` (movie_content) and another array of shape `(1, 20)` (user_normalized). To be able to take a dot product, you will have to reshape the user_normalized array to shape `(20, 1)` making the movie_content and user_normalized arrays "aligned" (that's what numpy likes to call it) for `dot` product.

Hence, your code will look like

```py
import numpy as np

distances = np.dot(movie_content, user_normalized[1].reshape(-1, 1))
```

Edit: This solution only works when user_normalized is a vector. In case user_normalized is a matrix, you will need to transpose it. See @amdex's answer for that case.

Comment: This answer works, but is incorrect in the general case because `k == t` in the code above. The transpose is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer above correct, it only works for matrices whose first dimension is exactly 1. Using the transpose of `user_normalized` (`user_normalized.T`) will work for more dimensions.

So, the short answer is: use

```py
distances = np.dot(movie_content, user_normalized.T)
```

The more involved answer is that the dot product is only defined for two matrices `X` and `Y` if the second dimension of `X` matches the first one of `Y`, i.e., `X` has shape `(M, N)` and `Y` has shape `(N, D)`. The result of the dot product is then a new matrix with dimensions `(M, D)`.

In your case, you have a `(27278, 20)` matrix, and a `(1, 20)` matrix. The transpose turns the `(1, 20)` matrix into a `(20, 1)` matrix, thereby satisfying the conditions for a dot product. The end result is a `(27278, 1)` matrix, where each cell contains the product of the Nth movie and Dth user.